# Automatically switch between a build and reporting DB i .NET 4.5 and SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I've inherited a .NET webforms dashboard application that runs off of a non-transactional SQL Server 2012 reporting database.

The reporting database takes 6 hours to build. Often this happens overnight when no users access the front-end. However, we have some new use cases which necessitate build during business operating hours, while users are trying to access the system.

While the database is still building, the data on the front-end is inaccurate.

I need a solution which enables me to have 2 separate databases - `build` and `serve`. The application should connect to `serve`. The databases should change roles dynamically - i.e. in build iteration (k+1), `build` becomes `serve` and vice versa. This will allow one static unchanging database to serve users in the morning while the latest database is building. As soon as it finishes building, the latest database becomes the serving one.

What is the best way to achieve this using these technologies?

I've considered 4 options so far and would like some feedback from the community before prototyping the implementations. I am by no means advanced at SQL Server so please forgive any ignorance in these ideas:

1. Do everything from SQL Server in the daily job. Have two MDF files `db1.mdf` and `db2.mdf`. Map the `serve` and `build` databases to these. At the end of the job script, rename the databases (keeping the filenames the same)
2. Rather than rename the databases, update the `ConnectionString` xml attributes in my .net application from T-SQL
3. Add some service to my application that enables switching of the active database.
4. Somehow leverage the database mirroring feature of SQL Server 2012.

What is the best way to go?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some comments:

Option 1, renaming, has the problem that if your dashboard app is running and has an open connection to the current live db while the rename happens I'm not sure what will happen. You will have an open connection due to connection pooling, even if the app isn't using a connection. The possibilities are a) the rename will fail, b) the rename will succeed but the connections in your apps connection pool will become invalid or c) it might all magically be OK.

If the connection pool connections become invalid, you'll need to catch the particular error and clear the pool:

```
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
    {
        SqlConnection.ClearPool(con);
    }
```

Option 2 I'm not sure how that would work but I have a suggestion below that might be along those lines.

Option 3 - I don't know what that might be so no comment.

Option 4, replication, might work, but you'd have to test it. If it takes 6 hours to build I wonder how long replicating the new db would take, though.

My suggestion: Have the two databases, but add a table with one row:

```
create table CurrentDatabase
(
    thisIsCurrent bit
);
```

When the time comes to swap the databases set thisIsCurrent = 1 in the one row in the newly active one and set it 0 in the inactive one. As part of every query you need to check this table first and if the current one no longer current then go for the other. You'll need a bit of global state to remember which is the current one. You'll also need two connection strings in the app.config, one for each db.

Comment: I like your suggestion. We use a lot of stored procedures in the application. Will having 2 connections complicate things for my DBML file etc? I.e. will I have to import the SP twice for each database or is .net clever enough to work around that?

Comment: Just give it a different connecion string and all will be fine (as long as the db scahmas match!).